# How to change string into array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

I am new to code, learning by myself and with the help of stack overflow.
I have one array, I want to pass another key value and want to make my string as an array, so that I can pass multiple key values.

Comment: Can you add the desired end result?

Comment: Please post proper examples of before/after since it's very unclear how you want the result to actually be. Showing is always preferrable. Exactly when and how do you need to add it? What have you tried? And what does this have to do with json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
array(
  "term" => array(
      "condition" => array("on", "off"),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, can you guide me for any free php tutorials

Comment: Tutorials? You bet? There are a lot, but Stack Overflow is not for tutorial recommendations.

Comment: A short array syntax exists which replaces array() with [], Using better the short array syntax.